# Highlight text in idle python

Tags: python-2.7, output, highlight

I try to output a highlighted text in Python IDLE but I couldn't get the result just like I want. Anyway I'd tried in Python exe it is able to highlight the text.

```
>>> from lazyme.string import color_print
>>> color_print('abc', color='pink')
[95mabc[0m
```

This is in python exe:

```
>>> from lazyme.string import color_print
>>> color_print('abc', color='pink')
abc
```

Anybody please help me on this. Is there any possible solution to this matter?
Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since IDLE shell isn't a terminal, it won't render the ANSI escape sequences.

So the result you got:

```
>>> from lazyme.string import color_print
>>> color_print('abc', color='pink')
[95mabc[0m
```

though it is correct, it won't render the color for you.